# Why does Python behave like this in nested function calls?

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I have 2 functions. The one that's the second one being called, takes a local variable from the first function and modifies it. I would expect this to use copies and not modify the original local variable, but it seems to be modifying it.

Example:

```
def a():
    dictionary = {"world": "hello"} 
    b(dictionary)
    print(dictionary)
 
def b(dictionary):
    dictionary["world"] = "goodbye"

a() # prints {'world': 'goodbye'} while I expect {'world': 'hello'}
```

What am I missing, isn't `b` supposed to work on a copy?

Comment: No it doesn’t work on a copy unless you explicitly copy it. It’s not modifying the local *variable*, it’s modifying the *value* associated with that variable.

Comment: In Python, arguments are passed by *assignment*, not by value. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference